# Facebook graph api single post policy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to post to multiple friends at once using the graph api (inside a iframed application tab), I'm sure I read that Facebook has a policy of only allowing you to post to one wall at a time, but I can't now find the policy. Did I make it up?

Comment: I have also read this, looking for the document. You haven't happend to have found this document?

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer the case, facebook now allows posts to multiple people as long as you indicate that to the user.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Social_Channels/

Answer (score 1):

This used to be clearly written in the policies, but it's no longer there.

I would caution against this however. See the following clause:
3. If a user grants you a publishing permission, you must still obtain consent from the user before taking any action on the user's behalf, such as publishing content or creating an event.

(this is found on http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

So you may need to explicitly request the user to approve each and every post first.